# How to list the devices attached to an ISA bus in Linux?

Tags: linux, hardware

The `lspci` command lists the devices attached to a PCI bus.

But in my case, the PCI bus also has an "ISA bridge" (not sure if this is what it's called) which has ISA devices connected to it. Is there a command that can list these ISA devices?

Comment: Most ISA devices are PNP, plug-and-play, i.e. they can be "discovered" by probing. They are mostly legacy or platform dependent, so you can see some under `ls /sys/bus/platform/devices/`, with the resources they use in `cat /proc/iomem` and `cat /proc/ioports`.